# Pass data from view to viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I want to pass data from view constructor to view model
This is my view which has a IEnumerable type parameter

```
    public SearchView(IEnumerable<ISearchable> enumerable)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

and i want to use same enumerable object in view model

```
    public  SearchViewModel() 
     {
      SearchCommand = new RelayCommand(TestSearch);
     }
```

how can i achieve this.Any help will highly apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do that when you loading the view. Take a look at my pseudo code:

```
   dependency property of type object objProperty = null;

   private object tempObj;

   public MyWindow(object param) : base()
   {
      tempObj = param;

      // create one way to source Binding
      Binding b = new Binding("DataContext.ViewModelProperty");
      b.Source = this;
      b.Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource;
      this.SetBinding(b, objProperty);

      // listen to DataContext changes
      this.DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged
   }

   private void OnDataContextChanged(...)
   {
       // push data to ViewModel 
       this.SetCurrentValue(objProperty, tempObj);
   }
```

This is how you can permit data from View to a ViewModel.

Everytime DataContext or better said the ViewModel changes you will push your value through Binding to the source.

Comment: in my case i want to access IEnumerable<ISearchable> enumerable which is constructor parameter in viewmodel. how can i do this will you more elaborate .Thanks

Comment: You seem to be asking for UnityContainer take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649614.aspx